# Возможно ли сохранить/обновить поле, в котором будет SQL?

Tags: yii

Возможно ли в Yii сохранить/обновить поле, в котором будет SQL в виде `NOW()` или `field_int*2`?

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно сделать нетривиальный sql запрос, его можно выполнить напрямую без ActiveRecord.

```
$sql = "нужный SQL запрос";

$connection=Yii::app()->db;
$connection->createCommand($sql)->execute();
```

Comment: Ну вот. Только начал разрабатывать на Yii, где никаких sql, как уже в простой задачке возвращаюсь к старому любимому SQL.
В таком случае не сработает onAfterSave() и прочие фишки

Comment: Через ActiveRecord время можно обновить так так

$post=new Post;

$post->create_time=new CDbExpression('NOW()');

$post->save();